Airflow PYTHONPATH
I am catching the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.marketing_functions'

Project structure example.
scripts/
├──__init__.py
├── marketing_functions.py
└── marketing/
    └── some_script.py  # Here my marketing_functions.py is used
dags/
    └── my_dag.py # Dag with bashOperator. it uses some_script.py with marketing_function.py import    


I put scripts into /opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts.
I put dags into /opt/bitnami/airflow/dags.
I add to PYTHONPATH /opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts. I see right PYTHONPATH using command "airflow info":

Paths info
airflow_home    | /opt/bitnami/airflow                                                                                                                                                                                 
system_path     | /opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin:/opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin                               
python_path     | /opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python39.zip:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/pyt
                | hon3.9/site-packages:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools-63.4.3-py3.9.egg:/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip-21.3.1-py3.9.egg:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags:/opt/
                | bitnami/airflow/config:/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins                                                                                                                                                  
airflow_on_path | True 

Dag code example:
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
        dag_id="marketing_some_script",
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 16),
        schedule_interval="30 2 * * *",
) as dag:
    some_script = "/opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts/marketing/some_script.py"

    task_some_script = BashOperator(
        task_id="task_some_report",
        bash_command=f"python {some_script}"
    )
task_some_script

Head of some_script.py file
from datetime import datetime

import gspread
import pandas as pd
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

from scripts.marketing_functions import *

Pls. Help me find solution.
UPD. Even if i just use python console i have the same problem:
I have no name!@0a8ff614c4b8:/$ python /opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts/marketing/some_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts/marketing/export_marketing_daily_report.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scripts.marketing_functions import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.marketing_functions'

BUT
I have no name!@0a8ff614c4b8:/$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts



There is no scripts inside /opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts. PYTHONPATH should contain /opt/bitnami/airflow in order to find scripts.

@mkrieger1 Thank you very much. I am so stupid... =( I spent about 10 hours trying to find a problem. Pls make the answer from your comment i will mark it as answer.

@mkrieger helped me with his comment:
"There is no scripts inside /opt/bitnami/airflow/scripts. PYTHONPATH should contain /opt/bitnami/airflow in order to find scripts"
